# Spring @Transactional + jdbcTemplate calling a web service

Tags: java, spring, transactions, jdbctemplate

My application is currently using Spring's `JdbcTemplate` and `@Transaction` annotation for transaction handling.

I have a method that calls a **web service** on a single transaction, and I designed it so that exceptions from the web service will rollback all database changes within the transaction.

my question: how can i FLUSH the database changes made before calling my web service?

many thanks

```
@Autowired
private MyDao dao;

    @Transactional
    @Override
    public void myMethod() {
        .....
        dao.saveThis(myObjectToSaveIsNotAnIssue);

        // I need to FLUSH here in order for my web service to "see" the saved object

       callWebservice();
    }
```

My spring config:

```
<context:component-scan base-package="com.xxx.xxx" />
    <context:annotation-config />

    <!-- proxy-target-class is set to true to use transactional scope -->
    <tx:annotation-driven proxy-target-class="true" transaction-manager="tomcatTransactionManager" />

    <bean id="sybaseDataSource" class="org.springframework.jndi.JndiObjectFactoryBean">
        <property name="jndiName" value="java:comp/env/jdbc/xxx"/>
        <property name="lookupOnStartup" value="true"/>
        <property name="proxyInterface" value="javax.sql.DataSource"/>
    </bean>

    <bean id="jdbcTemplate" class="org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate">
        <property name="dataSource" ref="sybaseDataSource"/>
    </bean>

    <!-- Transaction Manager -->
    <bean id="tomcatTransactionManager" class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DataSourceTransactionManager">
        <property name="dataSource" ref="sybaseDataSource" />
    </bean>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

JDBC doesn't have any "flushing" concept. The SQL queries are executed when you execute them. Nothing to be flushed is kept in memory.

Your web service won't see anything in database that you hasn't been committed, due to transaction isolation (which is READ_COMMITTED by default). You'll have to set the isolation level to READ_UNCOMMITTED if that's really what you want (in the web service):

```
@Transactional(isolation = Isolation.READ_UNCOMMITTED)
```

Comment: would that affect the rollback functionality in case an exception is thrown?

Comment: No. But your web service might take decisions based on information that hasn't been committed successfully yet (by the caller's transaction or by any other transaction), which is usually something you want to avoid (because the data might not even be in a coherent state, since it might read the result of half of another transaction)

Comment: yeah, I was expecting I will have problems at the web service side..... It looks like I will have to take the web service call out of the transaction, and create the rollback methods manually. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

We can take out callWebservice() method out of transaction in an assembler and then myMethod can called first from assembler, followed by callWebService() method.
And withinCall Webservice method, we can handle the success and failure scenarios. (Eg: update the status)